# Is there a way to use the YouTube API to embed a snippet of a video and grab the captions for just that part?

Tags: java, android, api, youtube, caption

I'd like to be able to pass the API a start and end timestamp to retrieve that snippet of the video, and then retrieve the captions for just that part of the video. Is this something that is possible?

If it helps, I'm creating an Android app using Java and I have a nodejs server that will make the calls to the YT API.

Comment: You could use an API - like - `youtube_transcript_api` = this is for Python, though - and there, from the results of the API, you can loop the transcript and search for your desired/expected captions. You can find an idea about what in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70414029/12511801) and the answer I posted there.