# Returning the time stamps of youtube videos based on a list of video ids

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api

> You can run my code in this google colab file --> https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Tfoa5y13GPLxbS-wFNmZpvtQDogyh1Rg?usp=sharing

So I wrote a script that takes a VideoID of a YouTube video like:

```
VideoID = '3c584TGG7jQ'
```

Based on this VideoID my script returns a list of dictionaries with the youtube transcript (the video content) like:

```
data = [{'text': 'Hello World', 'start': 0.19, 'duration': 4.21}, ...]
```

Finally I wrote a function that takes an input from the user, namely the word/sentence that you want to search and the function returns the time stamp with the according hyperlink.

```
def search_dictionary(user_input, dictionary):
        MY_CODE_SEE_GOOGLE_COLAB_NOTEBOOK


search_dictionary(user_input, dictionary)
```

```
Input: "stolen"

Output: 
the 2 million packages that are stolen... 0.0 min und 39.0 sec :: https://youtu.be/3c584TGG7jQ?t=38s
stolen and the fifth is this outer... 3.0 min und 13.0 sec :: https://youtu.be/3c584TGG7jQ?t=192s
```

---

Now comes my question. How can I apply this to a list of video_ids? E.g.

```
list_of_video_ids = ['pXDx6DjNLDU', '8HEfIJlcFbs', '3c584TGG7jQ', ...]
```

---

Expected Output:

```
Title_0, timestamp, hyperlink
Title_0, timestamp, hyperlink
Title_1, timestamp, hyperlink
Title_2, timestamp, hyperlink
Title_2, timestamp, hyperlink
Title_2, timestamp, hyperlink
Title_2, timestamp, hyperlink
```

So every mention within all the video_ids, not just a single video_id

Comment: You can loop the strings in `list_of_video_ids` and append the response of `transcript.fetch()` to your `data` variable in each loop. Search how you can append the results each time.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Can you please copy paste my code into your own google colab and apply your solution? I'm kinda stuck. I also thought looping over it would be easy.

Comment: I'm still learning Python, though, but, as a I read your code, you got it almost there. If not append elements to a given list/dictionary, try then, loop the response and in a separate list variable, add the results. Maybe I could get some time later, but, not now, sorry.

Comment: Ah okay, no problem. Take your time.

Comment: Thank you for share your code, I've change it and I hope it helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked you code and you just needed more time and tests.

As I [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70414029/returning-the-time-stamps-of-youtube-videos-based-on-a-list-of-video-ids?noredirect=1#comment124495559_70414029), you need to append the results of `transcript.fetch()` to a global variable - each time you loop the elements of `list_of_video_ids`, then, you can - in the `search_dictionary` function you created, iterate the transcripts.

This is the main code:

```
# Get user input here: 
# N.B: You should validate for avoid a blank line or some invalid input...
user_input = input("Enter a word or sentence: ")
user_input = user_input.lower()

# We use here the global list "all_transcripts": 
dictionary = all_transcripts

# Function to loop all transcripts and search the captions thath contains the 
# user input.
# TO-DO: Validate when no data is found.
def search_dictionary(user_input, dictionary): 
  link = 'https://youtu.be/'

  # Get the video_id: 
  v_id  = ""

  # I add here the debbuged results: 
  lst_results = []

  # string body:
  matched_line = ""

  # You're really looping a list of dictionaries: 
  for i in range(len(dictionary)): # <= this is really a "list".
    try:
      #print(type(dictionary[i])) # <= this is really a "dictionary".
      #print(dictionary[i])

      # now you can iterate here the "dictionary": 
      for x, y in dictionary[i].items():
        #print(x, y)
        if (x == "video_id"): 
          v_id = y
        if (user_input in str(y) and len(v_id) > 0):
          matched_line = str(dictionary[i]['text']) + '...' + str(dictionary[i]['start']) + ' min und ' + str(dictionary[i]['duration']) + ' sec :: ' + link + v_id + '?t=' + str(int(dictionary[i]['start'] - 1)) + 's'
          #matched_line = "text: " + y + " -- found in video_id = " + v_id
          
          # Check if line does not exists in the list of results: 
          if len(lst_results) == 0:
            lst_results.append(matched_line)
          if matched_line not in lst_results: 
            lst_results.append(matched_line)

    except Exception as err: 
      print('Unexpected error - see details bellow:')
      print(err)

  # Just an example for show "no results":
  if (len(lst_results) == 0):
    print("No results found with input (" + user_input + ")")
  else: 
    print("Results: ")
    print("\n".join(lst_results)) # <= this is for show the results with a line break.
# Function ends here.

# Call function: 
search_dictionary(user_input, dictionary) 

# Show message - indicating end of the program - just informative :)
print("End of the program")
```

Following this manner of thinking for this issue, I've modified your code and this is the link of your [Google Colab file modified](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16SU_fk8OKzPb550uUmgAPC2zgUJEWcR7#revisionId=0ByT15MFHHPVEem92YTlHdU82L0xKY0pkUWVYcFZVL0k5RHNBPQ).

This is the [Google Colab public notebook link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16SU_fk8OKzPb550uUmgAPC2zgUJEWcR7?usp=sharing).

The code is resume as follows:

- Your variable naming needs to change, due to - while testing, I was having issues understanding what kind of data I was dealing with = `lists` or `dictionaries`, it seems there are `both` = as you can see when you read the modified code.
- I advise you to organize your code and be focused on the spacing - there are lines way too long to read in Google Colab - this *might* be some personal preferences, though.
- As you can see in the comments I made in your code, I encourage you to add comments in your code - in order to help others to understand your code.

For test this code and see if it works with this modified code, try the input **`teach`**:

Bellow are the results:

```
Enter a word or sentence: teach
Results: 
teacher and set up a class or even...626.0 min und 4.079 sec :: https://youtu.be/pXDx6DjNLDU?t=625s
teach this process and where you watch...738.399 min und 3.68 sec :: https://youtu.be/8HEfIJlcFbs?t=737s
few times a year i teach a month-long...418.8 min und 3.44 sec :: https://youtu.be/3c584TGG7jQ?t=417s
End of the program
```

Comment: I really appreciate that you took your time helping me out on this one. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Just one thing... can you turn the google colab notebook public for anyone to see. By default colab notebooks are private and can only be accessed with a password

Comment: @MaximilianFreitag sure thing - this is the [public link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16SU_fk8OKzPb550uUmgAPC2zgUJEWcR7?usp=sharing) - please check it and let me know for any issues with this notebook. I'm glad my solution worked.